# Expose original Class from reference

Tags: c++, class, casting, reference

my iterator * operator returns a reference to class : File

```
   File& FilesIterator::operator*() {
         return *m_pFile;
   }
```

I created another class:

```
    class TextFile: public File
```

In another part of the code I need to expose public function of class TextFile 
after i use the * operator.

how can i do it?

Thanks

Comment: Which part is giving you the difficulty?

Comment: I also have class Directory :  public File

Comment: so how can I know if the File& that returns from the * operator is a TextFile or a Directory ?

Comment: @user3997340 _"so how can I know if the File& that returns from the * operator is a TextFile or a Directory ? "_ see 2nd part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> *"how can i do it?"*

Your code already does expose a reference, you'll probably just need that *function* to be declared in `File` as `virtual` or pure `virtual` function:

```
class File {
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class TextFile : public File {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        // Provide an implementation for foo()
    }
};
```

---

As for your clarification from [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30956580/expose-original-class-from-reference/30956649?noredirect=1#comment49946024_30956580):

> *"I also have `class Directory : public File`"*

Another way is just to provide a `virtual` destructor for `File`, `Directory` and `TextFile`, and use a `dynamic_cast<TextFile&>(*it);`:

```
 class File {
 public:
     virtual ~File() {}
 };

 class TextFile : public File {
 public:
     virtual ~TextFile() {}
 };

 class Directory : public File {
 public:
     virtual ~File() {}
 };
```

---

```
 int main() {
     Directory d("/my/directory/path");
     FilesIterator it = d.begin();
     while(it != d.end()) {
         File* f = &(*it);
         Directory* directoryEntry = 
             dynamic_cast<Directory*>(f);
         TextFile* textFileEntry = 
             dynamic_cast<Directory*>(f);
         if(directoryEntry ) {
             // Proceed with Directory specific code
         }
         else if(textFileEnty) {
             // Proceed with TextFile specific code
         }
         else {
             // Whatever ???
         }

         ++it; // Process next entry
     }
 }
```

Comment: when i use the second way you suggested I get an error when Im trying to cast while *it is of class Directory

Comment: @user3997340 Note that dynamic casting references will throw an exception, if the dynamic cast cannot be performed. Use pointers instead, I have updated my answer accordingly.